# Javascript keep decimal place

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am using the following code below to get the price from the attribute `data-price` which is assigned to radio buttons like so: `data-price="25.00"`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var frm = document.forms.myForm;
frm.onchange = function(e) {
var tot = 0;
for( var i = 0, l = frm.elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    if( frm.elements[i].checked ) {
        tot += parseFloat( frm.elements[i].getAttribute('data-price') );
    }  
}
document.getElementById('total').value = ( tot );
}
})
```

The problem I am getting is that when it dispalys it in the input box for the following example it would only show 25 I need it to say 25.00 is there a way around this?

Comment: have you tried adding tot+".00" ?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: A quick google of "javascript decimal place" brings up a whole slew of pages that mention toFixed()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tot.toFixed(2)
```

will give you the result.

And since you use jQuery, you could write more jQuery like code, just an example like below, just a suggestion:

```
$(function () {
    $('form[name="myForm"]').change(function () {
        var tot = 0;
        $('input:checked', this).each(function () {
            tot += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
        });
        $('#total').val(tot.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning `tot.toFixed(2)`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript won't show 25.00 if it is a number

```
console.log(25.00);
alert(25.00)
```

Both will show 25. It works only if there are non-zero digits after .

```
console.log(25.03);
```

So convert it to number for the calculations, and when showing in a text box use `.toFixed(2)` like others have suggested here.

```
document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
```

`toFixed` converts it to string.